# how to dynamically create element with ngModel attribute using ionic?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I'm trying to create `ion-input` element dynamically when user clicks on "+".Then I want to insert all values of inputs to an array. I created the inputs but I can's assign `[(ngModel)]` attribute to new elements. How can I do that?
This is the method that creates new element:

```
newElement() {
    const item = document.createElement('ion-item');
    const input = document.createElement('ion-input');
    input.placeholder = 'شماره سریال';
    input.type = 'text';
    input.required = true;
    input.name = 'serialNumbers';
    input.className = 'input inputSerial';
    input.ngModel='serialNumbers';
    const div = document.getElementById('newElements');
    console.log(item);
    item.appendChild(input);
    div.appendChild(item);
  }
```

This is the default input when the page is loaded at first:

```
  <ion-item>
  <ion-input
    type="text"
    expand="block"
    placeholder="شماره سریال"
    required
    name="serialNumbers"
    [(ngModel)]="serialNumbers"
  ></ion-input>
```

the `serialNumbers` array only accepts the value of the default input

Comment: you can use angulars `*ngIf` or `*ngFor` . Directly manipulating the DOM isn't recommended with angular. Also, `ion-input` is an ionic component and not a DOM element. `createElement` wont work with that

Comment: Thank you but how can I do that using *ngIf or *ngFor?

Comment: Is serialNumbers an array with each input for each number?

Comment: yes that's right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use angular templating for this. Directly manipulating the DOM is not recommended with angular. Use structural directives instead.

In your component class, have an array of inputs

```
serialNumbers: any = [];
```

In the component,

```html
<ion-item *ngFor="let serialNumber of serialNumbers;">
  <ion-input
    type="text"
    expand="block"
    placeholder="شماره سریال"
    required
    name="serialNumbers"
    [(ngModel)]="serialNumber"
  ></ion-input>
```

In your `newElement()`

```
newElement(){
    this.serialNumbers.push('');//default value.
}
```